# Retrieving Values from mysql table in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

my MessageController is as follows:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Message;


class MessageController extends Controller
{
    public function CreateMessage(Request $request)
    {

        $meso = new Message();
        $meso->body = $request['body'];
        $meso->subject = $request['subject'];


        $request->user()->messages()->save($meso) ;


       return redirect()->route('mail');
    }
    public function getmailbox()
    {
        $message = Message::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
        return view('dashboard', ['messages' => $message]);
    }
}
```

and i am trying to retrieve the messages here in my mail.blade.php:

```
<table class="table table-inbox table-hover">
                            <tbody>
                              @foreach($messages as $message)
                              <tr class="unread">
                                  <td class="inbox-small-cells">
                                      <input type="checkbox" class="mail-checkbox">
                                  </td>
                                  <td class="inbox-small-cells"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></td>
                                  <td class="view-message dont-show">Facebook</td>
                                  <td class="view-message view-message"><p>{{ $message->body }}</p></td>
                                  <td class="view-message inbox-small-cells"><i class="fa fa-paperclip"></i></td>
                                  <td class="view-message text-right">feb 14</td>
                              </tr>
                          </tbody>
                          @endforeach
                          </table>
```

However this is the result i get from that query :
**ErrorException in ed6d9659a06e690c67323133798cd26570bdc7a9.php line 200:
Undefined variable: messages (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\dating\resources\views\mail.blade.php)**
Any help here

Answer (score 0):

## Laravel 5

Change the function structure :

```
public function CreateMessage(Request $request)
{

    $meso = new Message();
    $meso->body = $request['body'];
    $meso->subject = $request['subject'];

    $meso->save();
    //$request->user()->messages()->save($meso) ;

    /**
    * You can get the last inserted ID 
    *
    * If your message table having primaty key column name is id
    */

    // $last_insert_id = $meso->id;


    return redirect()->route('mail');
}
public function getmailbox()
{
    $message = Message::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
    return view('mail', ['messages' => $message]);
}
```

Comment: i wa getting this error "ErrorException in ed6d9659a06e690c67323133798cd26570bdc7a9.php line 200: Undefined variable: messages (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\dating\resources\views\mail.blade.php) " while trying to retrieve the values from a database.

Comment: change getmailbox() description :

// return view('dashboard', ['messages' => $message]);
to -
return view('mail', ['messages' => $message]);

Comment: can you share me mail route structure ?

Comment: Route::get('mail', 'UserController@getMail');

Comment: anything yet?? i am having trouble with the messages retrieval

Comment: any clues yet??

Comment: SO change this route definition : like -- Route::get('mail', 'CreateMessage@getmailbox');

or show me 'UserController@getMail' definition